# use FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl with mp4parser v1.9

Tags: android, mp4parser

I'm trying to update one of our internal libraries that uses mp4 parser to v1.9 (we were using 1.1 before), and I succeded so far but I have one last problem (and I do not code in Java)

We have

```
// NOTE: Switched to using FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl since it does not use memory mapping (VM).
// Otherwise we get OOM with large movie files.

final Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(new FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl(src.getPath()));
```

like so many repositories, and this worked before but with the latest version I get

```
FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl cannot be converted to String 
final Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(new FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl(src.getPath())); ^
```

I tried switching to an absolute path or passing src directly but it does not work, we need FileDataSourceViaHeapImpl because some files can be big so we can avoid the OOM errors